# Есть ли языки программирования на основе русского языка?

Tags: любой-язык

/ *Спрашивающий, видимо, совсем не знает русского языка и пользуется автопереводом* /

Есть ли языки программирования или язык сценариев я могу узнать? Скажите, пожалуйста, все возможные и легко языков. Я начинаю интересоваться информатики. Спасибо!

Comment: Подтяните сначала свой русский...

Answer (score 4):

1. АНАЛИТИК,
2. Глагол,
3. Кумир,
4. Рапира,
5. Робик,
6. ДРАКОН.

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Встроенный_язык_программирования_1С:Предприятие